# Newbie to Sveltekit : how can i correctly create a json to base64 string .... without breaking another imported component

Tags: json, base64, buffer, sveltekit

I am a new learner to svelte development ...
i have become comfortable with django and python and moved on to learning some front end dev

i have so far created a totally independent front end that requires no back end

i am very new to svelte

so far everything has been a dream and getting everything working has been amazing

got my front end live done a lighthouse test and that's when it hit

my images load way to slow

with future developments in mind i set up a server-less image handler on AWS

now i have managed to figure out a few basic functions to use my image handler

i know i need to convert my json to base64 attached to the url and i am returned with  my edited and optimized image .

being new to svelte i looked for some options on how i can request specific images on the fly .

now when i use this code inside my

tags 

buffer is breaking my typewriter module 

i am pretty sure i am doing something wrong 

and maybe implement it in a way that is not good


        
        
            let clientWidth, element;
            $: measuredWidth = element?.getBoundingClientRect()?.width;
            let clientHeight
            $: measuredHeight = element?.getBoundingClientRect()?.height;
            let str = {"bucket": "ashleytaylors", "key": "background.jpg", "edits": {"resize": {"width": 1294, "height": 656, "fit": "cover"}, "webp": {"quality": 80, "force": true, "toFile": "background.webp", "toFormat": "webp"}}}
            let buff = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(str)).toString("base64");
            const urlir = `${"https://xxHIDDENxx.cloudfront.net"}/${buff}`
        
            import Typewriter from 'svelte-typewriter'

```
    <body bind:clientWidth bind:clientHeight class="font-sans antialiased text-gray-900 leading-normal tracking-wider bg-cover" style="background-image:url({urlir});">
    <div class="max-w-4xl flex items-center h-auto lg:h-screen flex-wrap mx-auto my-32 lg:my-0">
    <!--Main Col-->
        <div id="profile" class="w-full lg:w-3/5 rounded-lg lg:rounded-l-lg lg:rounded-r-none shadow-2xl bg-gray-200 opacity-75 mx-6 lg:mx-0">
            <div class="p-4 md:p-12 text-center lg:text-left">
                <!-- Image for mobile view-->
                <div class="block lg:hidden rounded-full shadow-xl mx-auto -mt-16 h-48 w-48 bg-cover bg-center" style="background-image: url('https://d1305lkq6ss4n8.cloudfront.net/city.jpg')"></div>
    
                <h1 class="text-3xl text-center font-bold pt-8 lg:pt-0">Ashley </h1>
                <div class="mx-auto lg:mx-0 w-full pt-6 border-b-2 border-blue-500 opacity-25"></div>
                <p class="pt-6 text-base font-bold flex items-center justify-center"><svg class="h-4 fill-current text-blue-700 pr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M9 12H1v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h14a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-6h-8v2H9v-2zm0-1H0V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h4V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v1h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v6h-9V9H9v2zm3-8V2H8v1h4z"/></svg>Web Stack Developer</p>
                <p class="pt-2 text-gray-600 text-xs lg:text-sm flex items-center justify-center "><svg class=" h-4 fill-current text-blue-700 pr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M10 20a10 10 0 1 1 0-20 10 10 0 0 1 0 20zm7.75-8a8.01 8.01 0 0 0 0-4h-3.82a28.81 28.81 0 0 1 0 4h3.82zm-.82 2h-3.22a14.44 14.44 0 0 1-.95 3.51A8.03 8.03 0 0 0 16.93 14zm-8.85-2h3.84a24.61 24.61 0 0 0 0-4H8.08a24.61 24.61 0 0 0 0 4zm.25 2c.41 2.4 1.13 4 1.67 4s1.26-1.6 1.67-4H8.33zm-6.08-2h3.82a28.81 28.81 0 0 1 0-4H2.25a8.01 8.01 0 0 0 0 4zm.82 2a8.03 8.03 0 0 0 4.17 3.51c-.42-.96-.74-2.16-.95-3.51H3.07zm13.86-8a8.03 8.03 0 0 0-4.17-3.51c.42.96.74 2.16.95 3.51h3.22zm-8.6 0h3.34c-.41-2.4-1.13-4-1.67-4S8.74 3.6 8.33 6zM3.07 6h3.22c.2-1.35.53-2.55.95-3.51A8.03 8.03 0 0 0 3.07 6z"/></svg>Location - nottingham, United Kingdom</p>
                <p class="pt-8 text-center text-sm">
                    <Typewriter cascade interval={100}>
                        <h1>Welcome, I love Coding ... my main hobby is to build efficient stack systems for the modern world take a look at my portfolio for examples</h1>
                    </Typewriter>
                <div class="pt-12 pb-8 text-center">
                    <button class="bg-blue-700 hover:bg-green-900 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full">
                        <a href="https://portfolio.xxxxxx.com">Check My Portfolio Out !</a>
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="mt-6 pb-16 lg:pb-0 w-4/5 lg:w-2/5 mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between">
                    <a class="link" href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=" data-tippy-content="@facebook_handle"><svg class="h-6 fill-current text-gray-600 hover:text-green-700" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Facebook</title><path d="M22.676 0H1.324C.593 0 0 .593 0 1.324v21.352C0 23.408.593 24 1.324 24h11.494v-9.294H9.689v-3.621h3.129V8.41c0-3.099 1.894-4.785 4.659-4.785 1.325 0 2.464.097 2.796.141v3.24h-1.921c-1.5 0-1.792.721-1.792 1.771v2.311h3.584l-.465 3.63H16.56V24h6.115c.733 0 1.325-.592 1.325-1.324V1.324C24 .593 23.408 0 22.676 0"/></svg></a>
                    <a class="link" href="https://twitter.com/" data-tippy-content="@twitter_handle"><svg class="h-6 fill-current text-gray-600 hover:text-green-700" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Twitter</title><path d="M23.954 4.569c-.885.389-1.83.654-2.825.775 1.014-.611 1.794-1.574 2.163-2.723-.951.555-2.005.959-3.127 1.184-.896-.959-2.173-1.559-3.591-1.559-2.717 0-4.92 2.203-4.92 4.917 0 .39.045.765.127 1.124C7.691 8.094 4.066 6.13 1.64 3.161c-.427.722-.666 1.561-.666 2.475 0 1.71.87 3.213 2.188 4.096-.807-.026-1.566-.248-2.228-.616v.061c0 2.385 1.693 4.374 3.946 4.827-.413.111-.849.171-1.296.171-.314 0-.615-.03-.916-.086.631 1.953 2.445 3.377 4.604 3.417-1.68 1.319-3.809 2.105-6.102 2.105-.39 0-.779-.023-1.17-.067 2.189 1.394 4.768 2.209 7.557 2.209 9.054 0 13.999-7.496 13.999-13.986 0-.209 0-.42-.015-.63.961-.689 1.8-1.56 2.46-2.548l-.047-.02z"/></svg></a>
                    <a class="link" href="https://github.com/" data-tippy-content="@github_handle"><svg class="h-6 fill-current text-gray-600 hover:text-green-700" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>GitHub</title><path d="M12 .297c-6.63 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.303 3.438 9.8 8.205 11.385.6.113.82-.258.82-.577 0-.285-.01-1.04-.015-2.04-3.338.724-4.042-1.61-4.042-1.61C4.422 18.07 3.633 17.7 3.633 17.7c-1.087-.744.084-.729.084-.729 1.205.084 1.838 1.236 1.838 1.236 1.07 1.835 2.809 1.305 3.495.998.108-.776.417-1.305.76-1.605-2.665-.3-5.466-1.332-5.466-5.93 0-1.31.465-2.38 1.235-3.22-.135-.303-.54-1.523.105-3.176 0 0 1.005-.322 3.3 1.23.96-.267 1.98-.399 3-.405 1.02.006 2.04.138 3 .405 2.28-1.552 3.285-1.23 3.285-1.23.645 1.653.24 2.873.12 3.176.765.84 1.23 1.91 1.23 3.22 0 4.61-2.805 5.625-5.475 5.92.42.36.81 1.096.81 2.22 0 1.606-.015 2.896-.015 3.286 0 .315.21.69.825.57C20.565 22.092 24 17.592 24 12.297c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12"/></svg></a>
                </div>
    
                <!-- Use https://simpleicons.org/ to find the svg for your preferred product -->
    
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <!--Img Col-->
        <div class="w-full lg:w-2/5">
            <!-- Big profile image for side bar (desktop) -->
            <img alt="" src="https://xxHIDDENxx.cloudfront.net/city.jpg" class="rounded-none lg:rounded-lg shadow-2xl hidden lg:block">
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    </body>
```

is there i way i should do this correctly or any npm modules i could use and implement

again iam very new to this so a solution and example would go a long way

my main goal is to measure any element containing an image and fill a json predefined string and then fetch the optimized image to suite who ever is browsing my page

i want to make it clear i want to use my serve-less image handler and not optimize the images using svelte this is so i can keep the same concept through out my future projects

i have been at this a couple days and it has me totally stumped

my image is working but my typewriter module then fails i can only have one or the other working

a solution and/or a better way of doing things i am open to anything

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

okay so more reading of the docs lead me to thumbor
using thumbor compared to base64 resolved my needs

```
    https://xxxhideeenxxx.cloudfront.net/fit-in/{width}x{height}/background.jpg?filter:format(webp)
```